# Make the string as parameter of sympy.latex function

Tags: latex, sympy

Help! I am learning sympy and have trouble with sympy.latex function. I want the sympy.latex function to take string as parameter, but in this case it doesn't work.
For example,

```
from sympy import  *

x, y, n = symbols('x y n')
print latex(n + x/y)
```

the output is : `n + \frac{x}{y}`

but when i write

```
myString = 'n + x/y'
print latex(myString)
```

output is : `n + x/y` 
although i want to see : `n + \frac{x}{y}`

What should I do?

Comment: ``latex`` works only with SymPy objects AFAIK. You should first convert the string to a sympy object. A simple solution should be ``latex(sympify('n + x/y'))``.

Comment: @Marshmallow Done :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you shouldn't rely on the fact that some SymPy functions happen to work with strings as input. You should convert strings to SymPy expressions first with `sympify`.

```
expr = sympify(myString)
latex(expr)
```

Answer (score 2):

`latex` works only with SymPy objects AFAIK. You should first convert the string to a SymPy object. A simple solution should be `latex(sympify('n + x/y'))`.